# Set views contextual filter as request_path()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

**Theme**

I have a content type with image and URL fields, I need to show image as banner on the path where URL field is matched with requested path using views.

I tried with

1-> adding "Alias" field as contextual filter in views.

2-> adding URL field

3-> I also tried with URL field with PHP Code in contextual filter:

```
if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
    return '<front>';
}else{
    return request_path();
}
```

3rd point works partially for only one path argument, like if current requested path is  `services/one` and views contextual filter only takes first path component as you can see in attached image
[image]
However, I need to set contextual filter with whole path no matter how many components are requested.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by embedding the views block in tlp and passing the URL field filter by code. See code below:

```
$path = request_path();

$query = 'SELECT field_url_url FROM {field_data_field_url}
          WHERE bundle = :bundle AND entity_type = :entity_type AND field_url_url =  :field_url_url';

$path = db_query($query, array(
                               ':bundle'=>'page_banner',
                               ':entity_type'=>'node',
                               ':field_url_url'=> $path
                 ))->fetchField();

if (!empty($path)):
  print views_embed_view('page_banner','block', $path);
endif;
```

I hope this will help someone who needs to add contextual filter as request URL.